# Spring boot app can't resolve SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, properties-file

I am currently deploying my spring Boot application on an external Tomcat. I configured a system property:

```
SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=/conf/Catalaina/localhost
```

And set my DataSourceConfig class to read it as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION}/application-${name}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class DataSourceConfig {...}
```

This works fine on my local Tomcat but not on the Server. Any ideas on why it won't work?
This is the error I get:

```
2017-09-22 08:59:00.019  INFO 27792 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassParser         : Properties location [file:${SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION}/application-${name}.properties] not resolvable: Could not resolve placeholder 'SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION' in value "file:${SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION}/application-${name}.properties"
```

Comment: How did you configure the system property ?

Comment: I used "export"

Comment: Drop your `@PropertySources`... Spring boot already loads them, you are working against the framework...